# If $f\in L^{2}(G)$ and $G$ is abelian, must $f(\cdot^{-1})\in L^{2}(G)$ also?

Tags: banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group.

Let $f\in L^{2}(G)$, i.e. $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ is measurable and $\int_{G}|f(s)|^2ds <\infty$ where the integral is taken with respect to Haar measure.

Define the function $\tilde{f}(s) = f(s^{-1})$ a.e. on $G$.

Is $\tilde{f}\in L^{2}(G)$?

Comment: In an Abelian group the Haar measure is invariant under inversion in the group.

Comment: facepalm.  I almost want to delete the question... now.  thank you Lord Shark

Comment: In general, if $\mu$ is a right Haar measure on the locally compact group, then $\bar\mu(A)=\mu(A^{-1})$ defines a left Haar measure. Uniqueness of the Haar measure (up to a constant) finishes the proof. However, the condition you are using (measurability implicitly assumed) defines $L^1(G)$, rather than $L^2(G)$, but it's not really relevant.

Comment: Indeed that was a typo (now fixed).  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a group and $\mu$ is a measure on $G$, then defining, for every measurable subset $A$, $\bar{\mu}(A)=\mu(A^{-1})$ gives a measure on $G$.

It's easy to see that if $\mu$ is right invariant (that is, $\mu(Ag)=\mu(A)$, for every measurable $A$ and every $g\in G$), then $\bar{\mu}$ is left invariant.

In particular, if $G$ is locally compact and $\mu$ is a right invariant Haar measure on $G$, then $\bar{\mu}$ is a left invariant Haar measure on $G$, because $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism of $G$ onto itself.

By uniqueness of (left or right) invariant Haar measures on $G$, if $G$ is abelian, then $\bar{\mu}=c\mu$, for some scalar $c\ne0$ (the *modulus* of $G$).

This answer your question: $\mu$ and $\bar{\mu}$ share the measurable sets and also the integrable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another question is that:  is $\tilde{f}\in L^2(G)$, if $G$ be a unimodular group?

Comment: indeed that is all that is required